# Dominion Hinterlands 2nd Edition Update Pack

Tags: dominion, dominion-hinterlands

Can I play Dominion Hinterlands 2nd Edition Update Pack without the original hinterlands expansion pack?
I know I need the full version of dominion for any of the expansions (and have that!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. The Update Pack will contain a complete set of kingdom cards for each of the 9 cards being added to Hinterlands 2nd Edition, and since Hinterlands did not include any additional components (like tokens or mats) you can combine these with any existing collection. In fact, if you have a full set of base cards and one other set of kingdom cards then you have everything you need for a single full game of Dominion.

This will not be true for all of the [Update Packs](https://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Update_Packs) - two of the cards in the Prosperity pack reference Victory Point tokens (which you could proxy), and a hypothetical future Alchemy Update Pack would presumably require you to have Potion cards.